# Css media query, target web browser less than 1024px wide and iPad in Portrait

Tags: ios, css, ipad

I'm working on a responsive site and I want to make the site react to the browser being made less than 1024px wide, and use those same styles for the iPad in Portrait.

However, if I apply a media query for styles when the browser is less than 1024 px like this

```
@media only screen and (max-width : 1024px) { /* styles */ }
```

They affect the iPad in Landscape which I don't want - how can I exclude the landscape iPad but include the Portrait iPad ?

Comment: How about using a smaller value than 1024 then?

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
@media only screen and (max-width : 768px) { /* styles */ }
```

iPad's width in portrait is `768px`.